How to use filter query which returns uploaded plans (filenames) to Roboflow Workspace/Project
In general I have 5 projects under my private workspace. I want to download the list of files which were uploaded to Dataset and those in annotating process.
The problem is I can't get Roboflow API to work.
For this example let's use those VARs:
WORKSPACE=private-workspace-123
PROJECT=example-project
PROJECT_URL=https://app.roboflow.com/private-workspace-123/example-project
API_TOKEN=3j5hj534h5j

Based on documentation: https://docs.roboflow.com/api-reference/workspace-image-query
I tried to create my own query:
curl --location 'https://api.roboflow.com/private-workspace-123/search/v1?api_key= 3j5hj534h5j' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"query": "project:app.roboflow.com/private-workspace-123/example-project", "pageSize": 100, "fields": ["filename", "tags"]}

Results in (I also tried other versions of that url like /browse or with http://):
Internal Server Error%                                                                                                                     

curl --location 'https://api.roboflow.com/private-workspace-123/search/v1?api_key= 3j5hj534h5j' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"query": "project:example-project", "pageSize": 100, "fields": ["filename", "tags"]}

Results in always full list of images in all projects:
  ],
    "total": 10775,
    "continuationToken": "WzE3Mjg5NDEyODdd"
}%    

I found out also a second API:
curl --location 'https://api.roboflow.com/private-workspace-123/example-project/search?api_key= 3j5hj534h5j' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"in_dataset": "true","pageSize": 500, "fields": ["name", "tags"]}'

it returns perfectly images from that project but ONLY 50 max and the response doesn't have e.g. {"continuationToken": "WzE3Mjg5NDEyODdd"} so I cannot get to the second page.

I tried myself and below curl works:
curl \
    --location 'https://api.roboflow.com/my-workspace-123/search/v1?api_key=SECRET \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{"query": "min-width:0", "pageSize": 10, "fields": ["filename"]}'

I get below response:
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "something",
            "filename": "file1.jpeg"
        },
        /* (...) */
    ],
    "total": 9999,
    "continuationToken": "tokenID"
}

My aim here was to display all images in my workspace, but reading documentation about search and this page from API docs I can add more fields to the search query and more fields that should be included within the response.
--- edit ---
Looking closer at your first query:
curl \
    --location 'https://api.roboflow.com/private-workspace-123/search/v1?api_key=SECRET' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{"query": "project:app.roboflow.com/private-workspace-123/example-project", "pageSize": 100, "fields": ["filename", "tags"]}

I'd swap project:app.roboflow.com/private-workspace-123/example-project with project:example-project. So your new curl should look something like this:
curl \
    --location 'https://api.roboflow.com/private-workspace-123/search/v1?api_key=SECRET' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{"query": "project:example-project", "pageSize": 100, "fields": ["filename", "tags"]}

---edit---
I tried variety of combinations and it seems this is a bug in Roboflow's API, can you try to use roboflow-python package?

I'm happy to use their python lib but unfortunately I checked the source code and couldn't find any methods implemented for this purpose of listing images in the project

This: "query": "project:example-project" was the first thing I tried by the query didn't resulted in anything. I will raise this on their Github

Yep, I realized after trying a few combinations with and without project, and also different lengths of project. Unfortunately documentation does not mention if project can be returned as one of the fields in response, that way min_width:0 would return all images within workspace and they you could group them based on project..

But how to get a project as one of the keys? Since it's not available anywhere. I could theoretically add name of the project as tag and then group them by the tag but maybe there is an easier way.
